# How to assign a Python script to a button in Libreoffice?

Tags: python, button, toolbar, libreoffice

I have a Python script that performs actions on text. How to assign script execution to a button on the toolbar?

For a Basic script, it does this:

> To assign a script to a new menu entry
> Choose Tools - Customize, and click the Menus tab.
>
> Click Add.
>
> In the Category list box, scroll down and open the "Application Macros" entry.
>
> You see entries for "Application Macros" (scripts in the share directory of your LibreOffice installation), "My Macros" (scripts in the user directory), and the current document. Open any one of them to see the supported scripting languages.
>
> Open any scripting language entry to see the available scripts. Select a script.
>
> A list of the script functions appears in the Commands list box. Select a function.
>
> Click Add to create a new menu assignment. The new menu entry appears in the Entries list box.

https://help.libreoffice.org/latest/en-US/text/shared/guide/scripting.html?&DbPAR=SHARED&System=WIN

This does not work. I can't get a list of python scripts to associate with a toolbar button.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! While you are waiting for an answer, please take the [tour] to learn how this site works, and you might want to read some pages of the [help], for example "[ask]".

Comment: Where is the script located — in the LO user or application directory perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

The instructions need to be updated, but it works after selecting *Macros* under *Category*. As an example, under *Application Macros*, expand *Capitalise* and find *capitalisePython*.

[image: capitalisePython]

Comment: I wrote my own script and want to assign it to a button on the toobar

Comment: @ТульскийСамовар: Where is the script located — please see my other comment. If you don't know where to put the script, then work through the tutorial at https://christopher5106.github.io/office/2015/12/06/openoffice-libreoffice-automate-your-office-tasks-with-python-macros.html. Details about locations and URIs are at https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/DevGuide/Scripting/Scripting_Framework_URI_Specification.

Answer (score 0):

It can get horribly complicated, digging into the depths of LibreOffice, to do this sort of thing.

I've found that you need to look at creating an `.oxt` file to deploy your script/s as an extension, including not only the python script but also an `Addons.xcu` file which defines menus, images used and toolbar buttons.

The easiest way to make sense of this is to look at a example someone else has created.

The simplest one I can think of, which is relevant is this one (note I created it).

https://extensions.libreoffice.org/en/extensions/show/bookmark-toggle

The `bookmarktoggle.oxt` file is a zipped file that you can open with any archive tool to see its contents and the structure of the files.

It will also open with Libreoffice and install the python script as a toolbar icon, with an Alt+1 hotkey.

I've re-tested it this morning and it still works (on Linux) LibreOffice Writer version 7.3.7.2

See Tools-->Extension Manager to remove